# How to create a Quick Action in macOS to remove the GPS data from images?

Tags: automator

The current slow manual way of removing GPS data from images is to double click or manually open the image in the Preview App, go to Tools menu, click the Show Location Info menu option, click the [GPS] button, and finally click the [Remove Location Info] button, and then save the image.

It's okay in a pinch, but gets tiresome quickly, especially if trying to process multiple images.

Was thinking that maybe a "Quick Action" can be created with Automator or similar, so it can be used in Finder by right-clicking on one or more images and actioning a "Remove GPS Info" quick action.

I'm running Catalina 10.15.7.

**Is this possible, and if so, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **Automator** *Quick Action* setting **Workflow receives current [image files] in [Finder]** and add a **Run Shell Script** *action* to it, setting **Shell: [/bin/zsh]** and **Pass input: [as arguments]**, using the following *example* **shell script** *code*:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/bin/exiftool -overwrite_original -gps:all= "$f"
done
```

---

**Notes:**

This **Automator** *Quick Action* requires the use of the *third-party utility* [**ExifTool**](https://exiftool.org).

Change the *fully qualified pathname* of `exiftool` to whatever it is on your system. On my system I install it to `/usr/local/bin/`, noting that the *directory* may not already exist.

Also note that as coded, this overwrites the *original image file*. If you do not want to overwrite the original, then remove `-overwrite_original` from the `exiftool` *command line options*.

To use, select the *image file(s)* in **Finder** and the select e.g. **Remove GPS Location Info** on the **Services** *menu/context menu*.

You can also assign the **Automator** *Quick Action* a *keyboard shortcut* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

Note that you'll need to pick a *keyboard shortcut* not already in use by **Finder**.

---

[image]

Comment: This works great @user3439894, but is there a way to be asked if the original file should be overwritten or duplicated, with a prompt?

Comment: @SemoTech, I believe that what I provided answers the OP as asked, and any deviation from that **after the fact** is subject for a new question, referencing this one as applicable. That said, you can do whatever you program something to do, so yes, an entirely different **Automator** _Quick Action_ can be devised to handle the scenario you mentioned in your comment to this answer. This would involve switching to a **Run AppleScript** _action_ with the appropriate **AppleScript** _code_ to prompt for which _action_ you want to take, then use a `do shell script` _command_ to run **ExifTool**.